# Как можно добиться эффекта плавного перехода между фоном и объектом в Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Не знаю как это называется правильно `Gradient Fade-In` или как-то по-другому , поэтому к примеру прикрепил изображения что я хочу получить

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD:**
@test123 Ваш шейдер странно себя ведет, меняет цвет моей платформи и не работает этот переход как нужно

*Мой объект*
[image: Мой объект]

*Ваш шейдер*
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD 2:**
*Это то что нужно получить на финале* 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Шейдер с плавным переходом альфы от 0 к 1, в зависимости от высоты?

Comment: Поправил ответ. >>Ваш шейдер странно себя ведет, меняет цвет моей платформи<< - вы наложили два материала, как вы сделали, так он себя и ведёт. Используйте один шейдер.

Comment: Да и в принципе, в документации прямым текстом сказано, что нельзя использовать более 1 материала. Даже ваш юнити жёлтым треугольником с восклицательным знаком предлагает вызвать шейдер из шейдера, а не лепить два материала.

Answer (score 4):

Попытаюсь показать, как бы это сделал на шейдерах я:

1. Нам необходимо ввести текстуру и цвет, чтобы вы полноценно смогли работать с материалом объекта в дальнейшем.
2. Объекты могут быть разными по высоте, значит нам надо ввести какой то коэффициент для каждого объекта, описывающий его высоту.
3. Введём коэффициент прозрачности, который будет показывать с какой скоростью исчезает объект с места перехода.

   ```
   Properties
   {
       _MainTex ("Albedo Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
       _TintColor("Tint Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
       _Transparency("Transparency", Range(0.0,1)) = 1
       _Height("Height", Range(0,100)) = 1
   }
   ```

Далее, указываем что нас интерисует альфа как объекта, так и текстуры:

```
    Tags {"Queue"="Transparent" "RenderType"="Transparent" }
    Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
```

Теперь объявляем с чем мы имеем дело (vert и frag функции):

```
    #pragma vertex vert
    #pragma fragment frag
```

Далее, простейшие операции:

```
        struct appdata
        {
            float4 vertex : POSITION;
            float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
        };

        struct v2f
        {
            float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
        };

        sampler2D _MainTex;
        float4 _MainTex_ST;
        float4 _TintColor;
        float _Transparency;
        float _Height;

        v2f vert (appdata v) {
            v2f o;
            o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
            o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.uv, _MainTex);
            return o;
        }

        fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target {
            fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv) * _TintColor;
            return col;
        }
```

Создаю сцену, и делаю материалы [image: Простой материал]

Теперь, так как у вертексов нет понятия "Bounds", то есть, мы не можем узнать, размеры меша (расстояние между двумя самыми дальними вершинами) по необходимой плоскости, мы воспользуемся пунктом 2, и проследим за нашей переменной, немного модефицируя шейдер:

```
         fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target {
            fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv) * _TintColor;

            if(i.vertex.y<_Height){
                col = fixed4(1,0,0,1);
            }

            return col;
        }
```

[image: Подбор высот]

На моём примере видна граница, которая нас интересует - эта граница будет показывать, откуда нам начинать прятать объект:

[image: Подбор высот]

Делаем очередную модификацию кода:

```
        fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target {
            fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv) * _TintColor;

            if(i.vertex.y<_Height){
                float y = i.vertex.y;
                col.a = 1-_Transparency*(_Height-y);
            }

            return col;
        }
```

Чтобы менять альфу относительно текущей высоты точки на экране, и подкручиваем параметр прозрачности _Transparency:

[image: Регулировка прозрачности]

В итоге, я получил результат для материала группы одинаковых объектов:

[image: Результат]

Полный листинг шейдера можно посмотреть [тут](https://pastebin.com/Uh1ZGi9q)

---

Вот готовый вариант по uv:

[image: Результат1]
[image: Результат2]

```
Shader "Custom/Test"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" { }
        _Height ("Height", float) = 0
        _Transparent ("Transparent", Range(0,2)) = 0
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Tags {"Queue"="Transparent" "RenderType"="Transparent" }

        Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
        LOD 100

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv     : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float2 uv     : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            };

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            float4 _MainTex_ST;
            float _Height;
            float _Transparent;

            v2f vert (appdata v) {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv     = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.uv, _MainTex);
                return o;
            }

            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target {
                fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);
                float y    = i.uv.y;

                if(y<_Height){
                    col.a = 1-_Transparent*(_Height-y);
                }

                return col;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: как можно реверснуты чтобы прозрачность была снизу?

Comment: развернуть направление отсечения if(i.vertex.y>_Height) и развернуть градиент альфы col.a = _Transparency*(_Height-y);

Comment: выше написал что не так

Comment: Спасибо, это не то что мне нужно ) мне нужно чтобы этот шейдер работал как градиент, например задаю один цвет, а второй прозрачной будет, чтобы создать плавной переход на цвет фона на каждой сторон куба (ещё прикрепил одно фото с примером что нужно получить)